# The document ".xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have used xcode 4.6 for past 4 months.

All apps are working fine till now.

Now i have received a new application source code for some changes.

When ever i executes the application. I showing an error that was

***`The document "DetailTransactionPage.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive.`***

*`Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development Target to preserve compatibility`*

Any interface builder is not able to open.

I have tried to open with 4.5.2, 4.3.3 as well but no use.

[image]

Comment: Did someone convert the .xib to Xcode 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I guess, the source code you have got may be built with different Xcode version rather than you are using right now.

So, I think you need to perform following steps.

1. Right click on XXX.xib file and select "Show File Inspector."
2. Go to Interface Builder Document.
3. Change Development option with the version of Xcode you are using.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Change Development option is Disabled

Comment: I think your xib is built with Xcode5. So you'll have to install Xcode5. Then it will work.

Comment: Same issue with me @user2732294...How to get rid of this?

Comment: It will because you didn't open that backup code project in xcode5 and made changes so it is going to work.

Comment: @user2732294: If your problem is solved then please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm getting "Deployment" and "Development" as "Not Applicable" options. How to go about this one?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Did you open your project in another xcode version rather than you are using right now? If it was working earlier then you can also replace the Xib file from your last backup. It should work. Tell me if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 8):

This error is caused due to a xib created from XCode 5. You need to install Xcode 5 to be able to change the compatibility properties for that xib file. After you install, and open the xib, you need to change the "Opens in" property and set it to "XCode 4.6" and "View As" set to iOS 6.1, both from File Inspector of the xib.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue when I upgrade xcode 6.4 to xcode 7. What I did to solve this problem is: delete the "LaunchScreen.xib" file.